# Twitter. Post status with media

Tags: android, twitter, scribe

Is it possible to upload images using Scribe-Java and twitter POST Url "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"? 
 [my source](http://pastebin.com/rwfr5Jyz) 
I get the response: {"request": "\ / 1 \ / statuses \ / update_with_media.json", "error": "Could not authenticate with OAuth."}

Comment: I received an answer from developer: "It is possible, but you need to create a multipart http request"

Comment: Did you get this working using scribes OauthRequest or did you take a different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to help out anyone else looking at this, a simple way to build the multi part is to add httpmime-4.0.1.jar and apache-mime4j-0.6.jar to your path and do the following.

```
        /* You will have done this bit earlier to authorize the user

    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(TwitterApi.SSL.class).apiKey("[YOUR API KEY]").apiSecret("[YOUR SECRET]").callback("twitter://callback").build();
    Token accessToken = Do you oauth authorization as normal 

    */  

    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json");
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    try {

        entity.addPart("status", new StringBody("insert vacuous statement here"));
        entity.addPart("media", new FileBody(new File("/path/of/your/image/file")));

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        entity.writeTo(out);

        request.addPayload(out.toByteArray());
        request.addHeader(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());

        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // you're all good
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The trade off here is of course adding the size of the 2 jars to your APK